# cordova app Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, cordova

i have an apache cordova App 
everything works fine in browser ripple emulator 
but when i build the release or debug apk , i cant see the logo image and fonts i have used in my views
i have tested apk with chrome inspector and there is error in console

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///android_asset/www/css/fonts/yekan.ttf
Failed to load resource:net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND 
file:///img/logo.png
```

from the source tab in chrome dev tools i can see both file are included in app

any suggestion why the app cant load resource ?

Comment: could you post your config.XML?

Comment: @user6599525 are u using visual studio ?

Comment: yes visual studio 2015